# Is it possible to use Jakarta ee 9 in OpenLiberty 20.0.0.2-beta and any version of MicroProfile?

Tags: jakarta-ee, open-liberty, microprofile

Is there a way in OpenLiberty (v20.0.0.2-beta or other version) to use jakarta ee 9 (either via`webProfile-9.0`or`jakartaee-9.0`or any jakarta ee only packages) with MicroProfile, preferably v4.0 but v3.0 would be OK too

Currently using jakarta + MP generates version conflicts for lots of features (CDI 3.0 vs 2.0, Servlet v5.0 vs 4.0 ..)
MP v4.0 is not based on jakarta ee and there no sign it will be soon

If so, how to use MP with jakarta ee 9 ?

If it is not possible, is there a timeframe when it will be possible?

My feeling is that we will have to wait months to be able to use MP with jakarta ee 9...Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible to use MicroProfile with Jakarta EE 9. A spec update would likely be required due to the package rename in Jakarta EE 9.

Answer (score 0):

The MicroProfile community is actively discussing the plans for their next release(s).  If Jakarta EE 9 is important to you, I would suggest adding to our Google Group discussions (or starting a brand new post):  https://groups.google.com/g/microprofile

Thanks!

One other clarification...  Your last statement about waiting months to use MP with Jakarta EE...  Since you didn't explicitly call out Jakarta EE 9 in this statement, I wanted to point out that OpenLiberty does support the use of MP with Jakarta EE 8.  It's the package rename in Jakarta EE 9 that MP doesn't support yet.